# How to add Printer service on Nmap localhost list?

Tags: printing

after run command

> Nmap localhost

I can't viewed "Printer Service on port 515" for list.

How to add Printer service on `Nmap localhost` list?

Comment: I try to make your questions cleared, but it's better if you could elaborate it in details.

Comment: This is pretty much the *same question* as your other two questions you've asked on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Port `515/tcp` is the `line printer spooler` port. You could run a print spooler to listen to port 515, but....

The modern, Ubuntu way is to use CUPS (Common Unix Printing System), which listens to the Internet Printing Protocol on port `631/tcp`. Read `man cups`. Administer CUPS with a browser pointer to `http://localhost:631`

And, an easier way to see what's listening (or not) to a port is with `lsof` (and you get more information):

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:515 -i tcp:631
[sudo] password for w3: 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cupsd   17693 root   10u  IPv4 4833522      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd   17693 root   11u  IPv6 4833523      0t0  TCP *:ipp (LISTEN)
```